# Connecting to Hikvision Camera using python and open cv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ip-camera, hikvision

i want to Connect Hikvision ip camera with python and open cv using this code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
cap.open("rtsp://yourusername:yourpassword@172.16.30.248:555/Streaming/channels/2/")

while(True):
     # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',ret)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

when i run my code i got this Error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Amin\Desktop\ip camera in py\csm.py", line 15, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame',ret)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:261: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::CvtHelper<struct cv::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 6 (CV_64F)
```

i test my camera whit VLCPlayer and it work perfectly!

i think the problem refer to opencv4!

how can i fix it? tnx a lot

Comment: just to clarify before doing this please turn off the encryption on the video as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is you are passing a `BOOLEAN` value instead a `Mat` value in `imshow()` function of OpenCV here:

```
cv2.imshow('frame',ret)
```

So you should pass the frame:

```
cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
```

`cap.read()` in `Python` returns two values, one is `Boolean` which shows whether or not the frame was successfully read, and the second one is the frame itself. So you should check for the `ret` if it is `true`, then show the frame.